# How to make a PubKeyHash into a PaymentPubKeyHash

Tags: plutus

Im reading through old Plutus code and it seems to be that you could use in the past
pubKeyHash with the mustPayToPubKey function now it asks for a PaymentPubKeyHash. How do you get around this if you want to send a value to an owners paymentPubKeyHash from a plutus script considering that there is no byte string implementation of a PaymentPubKeyHash?

I cant use PubKeyHash anymore in the mustPayToPubKey is there a way to convert this format?

Comment: you can get own PymentPubKeyHash with `ownPaymentPubKeyHash` inside Contract.  Or that is not your case?

Comment: no its not I had previously manually typed in a pubKeyHash as a data type to reference the owners pubKeyHash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple newtype https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/Ledger-Address.html#t:PaymentPubKey

you can import `Ledger.Address` and convert it with something like `PaymentPubKeyHash myPubKeyHash`, you can convert in the opposite direction with `unPaymentPubKeyHash`

Comment: thanks a ton it worked I've been trying to figure that out for days